# Let $ H/N $ is nilpotent quotient subgroup. Then is $ N $ characteristic in $ H $? If no, then what condition need?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is finite solvable group and $ H $ is normal subgroup. Let $ H/N $ is nilpotent quotient subgroup. Then is $ N $ characteristic in $ H $?  If no, then what condition need?

Comment: The group $G$ seems to be irrelevant. It seems like a longshot that any condition on $H/N$ could force a condition on how $N$ sits inside $H$ (besides normality).

Answer (score 1):

No, not true: [counterexample](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_special_linear_group:SL%282,3%29): $G=SL(2,3)$, $H$ the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ (so $H \cong Q_8$, the quaternion group) and take $N \cong \langle i \rangle$. I estimate your question is too general to give a proper condition on $N$ to conclude characteristicness.